# mysql subquery run once or multiple times equal to no of records?

Tags: mysql

Below is my query I used to give data to jquery datatables.
From this query, I need the result as well as the total rows count. So, I return the total rows count as subquery.

```
SELECT  m.*, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*)  
                FROM member m 
                INNER JOIN relationship r ON m.ID = r.Relative_ID 
                WHERE r.Member_ID=33) as TotalRows 
FROM member m 
INNER JOIN relationship r ON m.ID = r.Relative_ID 
WHERE r.Member_ID=33 
ORDER BY 1 asc 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Is the subquery to take totalrows running once or 10 times or many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` condition is applied before the `SELECT` statement, so you'll only be doing one subquery. This is the same reason for not being able to use SELECT aliases in `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Thhere is only a single sub-query, and this isn't joined to anything else out of the query, so I would assume it only runs once.

A query execution plan would give you a definative answer.